# Parametrizing the surface $x^2 = 1-z$ and $y^2 = z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

I am given the following exercise:

> Find the parametrization of the surface $C: x^2 = 1 - z$ and $y^2 = z$

I got to the following answer:

\begin{cases}
x &= \sin (t)\\
y &= \cos (t)\\
z &= \cos^2 (t)
\end{cases}

Unfortunately, there's no way to evaluate if my answer is correct on the textbook. Could someone please verify if that's the case?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not the only possibility, but it looks broadly correct.  You will need $t$ in a range $2\pi$.  This does not look like a surface to me; more like a closed curve

Comment: You have the equations of two surfaces (parabolic cylindres), intersecting along a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let check directly

- $x^2=1-z \implies \sin^2 t=1-\cos^2 t$
- $y^2=z \implies \cos^2 t=\cos^2 t$

and note that it is a curve defined by the intersection of two surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Adding up the equations, $x^2+y^2=1$. Any parameterization that fulfills this constraint can do.

E.g. your solution, or

$$\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2},\\y=\dfrac{2u}{1+u^2},
\\z=\dfrac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)^2},\end{cases}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}x=t,\\y=\pm{\sqrt{1-t^2}},
\\z=1-t^2,\end{cases}$$

...

[image]